# Why calling clEnqueueTask 3 times causes task to be executed 10 times?

Tags: opencl

I've created a simple kernel in OpenCL:

```
__kernel void test(int x){
    printf("test\n");
};
```

I'm calling it in a very simple program:

```
int main(){
    cl_int err;
    cl_int i = 0;
    cl_kernel testKernel;
    CL cl = initCL(1,(const char*[2]){"kernel.c"});
    testKernel = clCreateKernel(cl.program, "test", &err);
    clSetKernelArg(testKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_int), &i); 
    clEnqueueTask(cl.queue,testKernel,0,NULL,NULL);
    clEnqueueTask(cl.queue,testKernel,0,NULL,NULL);
    clEnqueueTask(cl.queue,testKernel,0,NULL,NULL);
    clFinish(cl.queue);
    return 0;
};
```

I was expecting "test" to be printed 3 times, but instead, the output of that program is:

```
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

Why?

Comment: What is your work group size?

Comment: @BrianCain: It's a task, not an NDRange. So no work group size.

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: Macbook Pro Retina 2014... that is a GeForce 750N right.

Comment: If you have Nvidia Visual Profiler, gather application timeline & look, what were exact ND sizes of kernel launches.

Comment: what happens when you queue the task only once? twice?  what about 3 different printf strings in 3 different kernels, each called once?

Comment: People at #opencl determined it is probably a printf buffering issue, I managed to determine the kernels are actually being called the expected amount of times.

Comment: I'm glad you found out what was going on. Maybe post it as an answer for people searching this in the future?

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure this is the issue. That was their guess.